# I have an unexpected `junit.framework` error among my junit test

Tags: java, android, junit

I have searched all over the stackOverFlow about this error but non of answers could solve my problem.

I want to tun this test on real server.
this is my test in androidTest package:

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MultiFactorAPIAndroidTest {

    public ValidatePhoneUserRequest validatePhoneUserRequest;
    public LiveData<ValidatePhoneUserResponse> validatePhoneUserResponseLiveData;
    protected MultiFactorHelper multiFactorHelper;
    public String mLoginUserName ="12345678";
    public String mPIN = "456789";
    public String mTOTP = "kronikare";
    public String mSessionID;
    public String mUserRoleID;
    private MultiFactorAPI apiService;

    @Test
    public void testCallBackIsTrue () throws Exception {

        ValidatePhoneUserRequest validatePhoneUserRequest= new ValidatePhoneUserRequest();
        validatePhoneUserRequest.setUserUniqueID(mLoginUserName);
        validatePhoneUserRequest.setTotp(mTOTP);
        validatePhoneUserRequest.setPin(mPIN);
        validatePhoneUserRequest.setPhoneUniqueID("95847258");

        validatePhoneUserResponseLiveData = multiFactorHelper.getValidatePhoneUserResponse(validatePhoneUserRequest);
        validatePhoneUserResponseLiveData.getValue().getSessionID();
        if (validatePhoneUserResponseLiveData.equals(validatePhoneUserRequest)){
            assertTrue("test is true",true);
        }
    }
}
```

the error is:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.kronikare.kdcai.java.MultiFactorAPIAndroidTest
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:195)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:181)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:564)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2152)


Tests ran to completion.
```

Comment: Can you post the tracking error ?

Comment: sure, I've put it

Comment: Generally is it possible to execute such as this test on  a real sever instead of mock sever?
if yes is it necessary to write any thing in @before ?